# Laptop freezing with screen tearing after SSD migration(NOT BSOD)

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, display, freeze, intel-rst

I have an Asus Zenboox UX32VD laptop. Using Intel RST,  I migrated the SSDs into a single volume( I regret doing this), after that my laptop started acting strange.

First of all, the laptop got restarted one too many times ( by me ) during migration because the completion percentage got stuck at a digit for far too long.

(i know I'm an Idiot)

After that I tried running the scheduled fix of RST, which completed the migration after too many trials ( everything was freezing up randomly, then I had to kill the laptop with the powerkey.) Then half of my SSD was gone, it wasn't shoeing in device manager, neither in disk Management, only the single volume. The volume's data was also half and there was no unallocated space either. Renaming the volume from Volume 0000 to Disk 1 brought back the unallocated screen but then randomly screen goes on like this.

** Can't upload image due to zero reputation, pls check the link **

https://ibb.co/nxMZYa
I cannot do anything on the laptop unless I kill it's power again to restart it. It works fine for sometimes and then the screen goes like that image. I've tried system restore and some local troubleshooting but nothing seems to work, my internet is too slow to reinstall the display driver.

I know I know shit about laptops, can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the video driver might be your best bet. I'd suggest downloading it from the Asus website using a friend's WiFi or at your local coffee shop/college campus. Be sure to download the latest one. It should return your video settings to normal.

https://www.asus.com/in/support/Download/3/411/0/2/Z9zboGSUuWyLgwXV/30/

Comment: The screen cutting seems to go away (I re-installed the graphics driver just to be safe), but the system still slows down terribly or freezes up at startup. Also, doing something processor-heavy freezes the laptop, which wasn't an issue before all this fiasco happened.

Comment: UPDATE: The tearing screen came back. It seems reinstalling the video driver gave no help.

Comment: I've also noticed that the back of my laptops unusually heats up and that's where the screen gets all teared up as well as the laptop frozen

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about this issue. It appears the SSD became corrupted or damaged by the migration attempt. It is not good to power off/reboot during these processes as it can damage important files.

Replacing the SSD and re-installing the OS might be the best way to go at this point.

You can create a bootable Kali Linux disk and boot into that to retrieve your files and back them up to an external device prior to the re-installation of your OS.

It's tough, but this is the quickest solution to your issue. Let me know if you come across any other info. I'd like to know if you are successful in restoring your laptop.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. At this point, my system won't boot up anymore... Only the power button and caps key lights up, the screen doesn't even start aswell. It's just heating up too much in this state, nothing else.